# Links in iFrame tabs won't work in Facebook application in Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I had links that worked before timeline, and since we moved to timeline, they don't. We are using the Facebook iFrame for our content.

What is going on? When we click on the link, it seems like something is blocking the browser from changing the page.

http://www.facebook.com/Activis?v=app_179997328701001

Edit : I'm still investigating that problem; One thing I should mention is that only links that go to another Facebook App don't work. The ones that go to something else than Facebook (A blog, Twitter and Linkedin) work fine.

Comment: Which Links? The links at the bottom work for me

Comment: The ones at the top of the page (in the iframe)

Comment: Is the target of the links the same frame? I find sometimes that facebook doesn't let you redirect to an iframe of facebook. E.g - Make sure you either set the link to target="_top" or make sure it is a full url of an app and not the app on facebook. Otherwise you're basically loading an iframe of facebook, with an iframe of your app within the existing iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TommyBs Wrote:

> Is the target of the links the same frame? I find sometimes that facebook doesn't let you redirect to an iframe of facebook. E.g - Make sure you either set the link to target="_top" or make sure it is a full url of an app and not the app on facebook. Otherwise you're basically loading an iframe of facebook, with an iframe of your app within the existing iframe

Yup, putting a target="_top" on my links worked. Thanks!